# How to save the results from docker on a mac

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow with docker. I've been struggling to save test results to a txt file outside of docker.

Is there a way to save results on my mac? For now, I can only write results to a txt file within docker.

Comment: Look into volume mounts.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a **data volume** when you run docker.

By doing so, your container and host (mac in your case) can share data.

You can do that with a command like:

```
docker run -v /Users/<path>:/<container path> ...
```

The `/Users/<path>` directory in your `mac` will be shared and the directory corresponds to `/<container path>` in your container.

After running docker with the data volume, just save your txt file in `/<container path>`. Then, you're good to go.

You can reference [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#data-volumes) for a more detailed description about data volume.